# Find a file in a directory using vb 6.0

Tags: vb6

Someone please help me 
"Searching a file (with any extension) in a directory using VB 6.0 codes and 
the code shall return TRUE if desired file is found in the specified directory else FALSE"

thanks

```
Private Function CheckPath (strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Dir$(strPath) <> "" Then
        CheckPath = True
    Else
        CheckPath = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: I think my question has been might have been misunderstood the follwing code have been tried. Please check the same. Thanks              Private Function CheckPath(strPath As String) As Boolean
    If Dir$(strPath) <> "" Then
        CheckPath = True
    Else
        CheckPath = False
    End If
End Function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a VB6 function to check whether a file exists or not:

```
Public Function FileExists(ByVal FileName As String) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    FileExists = Not CBool(GetAttr(FileName) And (vbDirectory Or vbVolume))
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Pass in the full filename including the file path.

Comment: Here's the +1 you deserved, curiously omitted by the asker despite accepting your answer. But I nevertheless feel compelled to point out that checking for the existence of a file isn't as necessary as it seems like it would be in the majority of cases. Even if you confirm the file's existence right before you attempt to manipulate or interact with it, you'll still be subject to a race condition. It's best just to attempt whatever file operations you need and handle the errors that result.